# writing a script which compiles with gcc

Tags: bash

I want to wrote a script which compiles a given .c file.
The script takes as first argument .log file and as a second argument the name of the program to be compiled.

Example:

```
./compile logfile.log helloworld
```

now I need also to compile with the gcc compiler so i'm using this command:

```
gcc "program name".c -Wall -g -o "program name"
```

so now my question is: how do I get the output of the gcc command to the .log file?

Comment: Hey, guys, not every question that mentions the word "compile" belongs on [SO].  This is a shell scripting question, not a C question.  That said, it's probably a dupe, and definitely shows no research or effort to solve it.

Comment: I would consider writing a `Makefile` and use `make`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect stdout and stderr to first argument of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc "$2".c -Wall -g -o "$2" >"$1" 2>&1
```

Usage (e.g.): `./compile.sh logfile.log helloworld`

Comment: Or use the easier to remember bashism `&>`.

Comment: I've fixed [two bugs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/272352/revisions).